# MySQL Full-text search - search for short words

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, full-text-search, search-engine

I have a problem. I made a simple search engine which searches by brand and model of car. For reasons of query performance and a lot of data in database, I decided to use full-text search. It's ok, but now I come across the problem:

I would like to find all cars with brand "Audi" and with model "Q7". For now, I have this SQL query, but it doesn't work right, because of word length "Q7":

```
SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`title`, `a`.`askprice`, `a`.`description`, `a`.`picture`
FROM (`mm_ads` as a)
WHERE `a`.`category` =  '227'
AND `a`.`askprice` >= '0'
AND `a`.`askprice` <= '144000'
AND (MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('+audi +q7' IN BOOLEAN MODE ))
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 30
```

I don't have access to modify MySQL config file, to set `ft_min_word_len` to value 2. For now value is 3. Is there any other way to deal with that?

---

Here is another problem:

I would like to get all cars brand "BMW" and model "116". For example, I have a car named `BMW, 1, 116i`. My SQL query is:

```
`SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`title`, `a`.`askprice`, `a`.`description`, `a`.`picture`
FROM (`mm_ads` as a)
WHERE `a`.`category` =  '227'
AND `a`.`askprice` >= '0'
AND `a`.`askprice` <= '144000'
AND (MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('+bmw +116' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 30`
```

Search return 0 rows. Why? All input strings ("BMW", "116") are min length 3. What am I doing wrong?

Regards, Mario

Comment: you will have to use non full text searching for the smaller words.

Comment: From what I've seen, it isn't possible without editing the ini file.  On top of that, this isn't a very good solution for the type of searching you're doing. I'd recommend just using something similar to `LIKE ('*bmw*') AND LIKE ('*116*')`.  It would return very similar results, and allow a lot more flexibility.  Though fulltext is a much simpler solution, it definitely isn't the best fit.

Comment: @mazzzzz I understand. LIKE is in this case much more flexibility. But, is faster? I really need to consider query performance..

Comment: They should be about the same performance, but if you are worried about it, why not make your own keyword table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue when dealing with match against (regarding text length) and my answer was to strlen the string first and switch between like and match against for shorter words. Not what I would call graceful, but it was all I could do since I too had no access to the config.

As for the second question, are you sure the default isn't 4? I recall I couldn't search on the term "art" in my case. 3 letters. Had to go with like on everything below 4 chars.

Comment: here's the mysql link. it is indeed 4 characters by default: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: No, my default value is 3, look at the image I've made: http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/3958/fulltext.jpg. So I guess I should switching between `LIKE` and `Full-text`.

Comment: There is another funny thing. I have car named `BMW, 320, e36` and if my full-text search looks like: `(MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('+bmw +(320)' IN BOOLEAN MODE))` there is 1 result - OK. But I have car named `BMW, 1, 116i` and my full-text search look like: `(MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('+bmw +(116)' IN BOOLEAN MODE))` there is 0 results. Why? How is 116 so different from 320?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are testing these queries without the price conditions, right? I assume the category 227 is cars, or something so that should be common between them. can you experiment and see if that 116i makes the difference? It could be that the boolean is false for 116 because it is strictly not 116i. I think () in match against makes second required, but it is intended to compare more than one string. so you are looking for bmw AND 116, which may fail if the i is not included. for model numbers, try using the base number only with an astericks - in this case 116\*

Comment: Yes, query is without price conditions and category ID 227 is common between them.. Hmm.. You are right. I solved my problem using `166*` with astericks at the end.. Before I tried search with astericks, there is 1 result for search with `116i`. Now, problem is temporary solved.. I just want to make sure, Full-text search is quicker the LIKE, right?

Comment: So long as you have an index defined on full text searches, I believe full text is always faster since like uses wildcard placement % to scan. I doubt either makes a difference in smaller databases, ie a few hundred thousand entries or so. But in massive databases, like amazon or ebay or something, the difference can be enormous.

Comment: Thank you. The team that takes care of server actually changed the value of variable `ft_min_word_len` to 2. So I'll no longer need a combination of `LIKE` and `FULLTEXT`. My problem is solved!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have access to the config file and can change it I fear there is very little to do.

A change to ft_min_word_len requires a server restart and a full rebuild of the full text index.

[As found here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

Comment: Otherwise, I wrote to the team who is in charge for servers. I seriously doubt that just because one customer (me) they would reset the entire server. We'll see .. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

for this search: "bmw 116i"

(MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ('+bmw +116i "bmw 116i"' IN BOOLEAN MODE ))

not the best solution but might help...