# Query with MATCH AGAINST a string returns more than strict equality to the string

Tags: mysql, match, match-against

I am trying to select products using `MATCH AGAINST` in MySQL.

The titles have a length specified as a single digit plus the letter `m` for meters, ie `1m`, `2m`, `5m` etc.

When I try to match `5m network cable` with the query below, it also returns `0.5m network cable`, `1.5m network cable` etc.

How can I get an exact word `MATCH` on a 2 character string?

My query:

```
SELECT title, category, price
FROM products_table
USE index (prod_idx)
WHERE (MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+"5m" +"network" +"cable"' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in SQL, so I don't have the answer, but it could be that `1.5m cable` is not selected because it contains `5m`, but because it contains `cable`, said otherwise you may have a *OR* operation rather than the *AND* you wanted.

Comment: no experience of MATCH AGAINST but some on full text indexing and what pops in my mind is that the `.` sign is interpreted as then end of a sentence, not the decimal sign.  Hence your results.  No idea, though, on how to configure mysql for that.  Perhaps the locale ?

Comment: Also there is the problem of full-text search on short words that are ignored. Just in case. [MySQL Full-text search - search for short words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301586/mysql-full-text-search-search-for-short-words)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FULLTEXT think of '.' as a word ender/starter/separator, but you want to think of it as a letter.  So, turn it into a letter:

When inserting data, change '.' to '_' so that 0.5m becomes 0_5m, which will treated as a word.  Do the same change in the search string.